# Command output is not redirected to file

Tags: command-line, grep, execute-command, redirect

I want to execute the following command, which is related to Rational ClearCase. The output of this command should be redirected to the file
`testout`.

### Command

```
rgy_check -vobs > testout
```

### Output

```
rgy_check.exe: Error: An unregistered region \<region> was found in
VOB tag entry.
rgy_check.exe: Error: An unregistered region \<region> was found in
VOB tag entry.
...
```

The file `testout` is created, but somehow the file is empty.

Grep also doesn't work, it still gives the original output

```
rgy_check -vobs | grep "06a89"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are error messages. The standard is to write normal output to the STDOUT stream, which you can redirect with `>`, and to write error messages to the STDERR stream which is redirected with `2>`.

Without redirecting, both STDOUT and STDERR end up on the terminal without a way for you to tell what's what.

So if you want your error messages to end up in `testout` redirect them with

`rgy_check -vobs 2> testout`

However, from your question, I suppose that `testout` needs to get the normal output. You could do something like:

`rgy_check -vobs > testout 2> testerr`

If you need to `grep` the STDERR stream, this is a little trick to do so:

`rgy_check -vobs 2>&1  > testout | grep something`

This will first redirect STDERR to the same file descriptor as STDOUT, then redirect STDOUT (but *not* STDERR) to the file `testout`, then pipe the STDERR output to the `grep` command.

Comment: Thank you this works. Follow-up question: How can I use the pipe-Operator with stderr (for the grep command)?

Comment: @Andymeissner Yes. It is quite simple if you are in Bash, use `|&` (see `man bash` for more information).

Comment: @Quasímodo Thank you, also for the reference

Comment: I added another way of doing that.