# Why is console output not stored in my log file?

Tags: command-line

I tried to run this command:

```
$ python flathunt.py >> job.log
[2022/01/16 20:33:49|config.py         |INFO    ]: Using config /home/adam/flathunter/config.yaml
```

according to my understanding from [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) the output `[2022/01/16 20:33:49|config.py         |INFO    ]: Using config /home/adam/flathunter/config.yaml` that was caused by `flathunt.py` script should have not been printed on the screen but stored in the `job.log` file. However, the opposite is true, the `job.log` is empty. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try ... `2>>` ...?

Comment: @FedKad if use 2>> then I cannot see anything in terminal but its stored in the log file.

Comment: I am using this script: https://github.com/flathunters/flathunter/blob/main/flathunt.py

Comment: See [Command output is not redirected to file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269712/command-output-is-not-redirected-to-file)

Comment: @steeldriver But in the linked script an info is logged not an error `self.__log__.info` https://github.com/flathunters/flathunter/blob/main/flathunter/config.py#L26 - so this does not answer my question, right?

Comment: @Adam based on `help(logger)` it looks like the logger object's default handler writes to the error stream regardless of the message level (*"If stream is not specified, sys.stderr is used."*)