# How to change the input and output path of the time command

Tags: bash, scripts

I want change i/o of the time command, lake the following commands, but they are wrong and do not work.  How to do this correctly?

```
time echo hello > log

bash -c 'time echo hello' > log

echo $(time echo hello) > log
```

Comment: Read `man test`. `test` does not read STDIN, does not write STDOUT or STDERR, it just sets `$?` (`$STATUS`). What do you want to change?

Comment: @waltinator if the OP is using bash, then `help test` is likely more pertinent than `man test`. AFAIK both the bash shell builtin `test` and external `/usr/bin/test` *do* write to the standard error stream (and will do so in this case ex. `test: echo: unary operator expected` or `/usr/bin/test: missing argument after ‘hello’`).

Comment: The bash `>` operator only redirects the standard output stream - if you want to redirect standard error to a file, see this similar question [Command output is not redirected to file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269712/command-output-is-not-redirected-to-file)

Comment: I'm so sorry. test no. TIME

Answer (score -1, accepted):

time (sleep 1 ; echo hello >log1) 2>log2

Comment: time (command) 2> outfile